# How to estimate G matrix in MARSS package in R?

Tags: r

I want to estimate and/or specify the matrix G in MARSS. My model looks as follows:

```
X_{t+1} = B*X_{t} + G*W_{t}
Y_{t} = Z*X_{t} + V_{t}
```

To this end, I use the following code as described in the MARSS UserGuide:

```
# Create some random data
M=100;
y1 = rnorm(M);
y2 = rnorm(M);
y3 = rnorm(M);
Y = matrix(c(y1, y2, y3), 
           nrow=3, ncol=100) 

# 1st case: Estimate SS model with restrictions on G
Z=matrix(list("z1","z2",0,0,"z2",3),3,2)
A=matrix(0,3,1)
R=matrix(list(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),3,3)
G=matrix(list(1,1,1,1),2,2)
B=matrix(list("a","b","c","d"),2,2)
U=matrix(c("u","u"),2,1)
Q=matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2,2)
x0=matrix(c("pi1","pi2"),2,1)
V0=diag(1,2)
model.gen=list(Z=Z,A=A,R=R,B=B,G=G,U=U,Q=Q,x0=x0,V0=V0,tinitx=0)
kemfit = MARSS(Y, model=model.gen)
```

```
# 2nd case: Estimate G and other parameters in SS model
Z=matrix(list("z1","z2",0,0,"z2",3),3,2)
A=matrix(0,3,1)
R=matrix(list(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),3,3)
G=matrix(list("g1","g2","g3","g4"),2,2)
B=matrix(list("a","b","c","d"),2,2)
U=matrix(c("u","u"),2,1)
Q=matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2,2)
x0=matrix(c("pi1","pi2"),2,1)
V0=diag(1,2)
model.gen=list(Z=Z,A=A,R=R,B=B,G=G,U=U,Q=Q,x0=x0,V0=V0,tinitx=0)
kemfit = MARSS(Y, model=model.gen)
```

In both cases, when running `kemfit` I get the following error message:

```
Error in chol.default(denom) : 
  the leading minor of order 2 is not positive definite

Stopped at iter=1 in MARSSkem at B update. denom is not invertible.
 Type MARSSinfo('denominv') for more info. 
 par, kf, states, iter, loglike are the last values before the error.
 Try control$safe=TRUE which uses a slower but slightly more robust algorithm.
 Use control$trace=1 to generate a more detailed error report. See user guide for insight.
```

Can anyone please tell what's wrong?

Comment: You are using a fixed G matrix, so it will not be estimated. However, your B matrix will be estimated. are you sure you want to estimate matrix G and not B?

Comment: I have 2 cases, in the first case I want to place restrictions in G. In the second case want to estimate the elements in G. Replacing the numbers in G with parameters to be estimated also renders error message. B is to be estimated in both cases.